# How can I reinstall php and apache on mac? I deleted some important php folders

Tags: php, macintosh

How can I reinstall php on mac? 
I think deleted some important php folders. 
I can't find the great solution with even google.

It's showing like this.

macui-MacBookPro:~ mac$ sudo apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 181 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php@7.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so, 10): image not found

Thank you

Comment: How did you install php to begin with?

Comment: brew. and I succes this problem myself. thx.